# What is Windows Phone 7/8 device driver model?

Tags: windows-phone-7

What is the device driver model for Windows Phone 7/8 ? I heard sometime back Windows using same philosophy as in iOS where in app can run both on desktop and mobile so I was in impression both Windows 7 (Desktop)  and Windows Phone 7 will have common device driver model may be WDF (Windows Driver Foundation)?

Your inputs much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed something.

There are:

- Windows Phone 7 applications. You can run them only on WP7 and WP8 devices (or in Emulator on desktop pc).
- Windows Phone 8 applications. They can run on WP8 device and in Emulator.
- Windows 8 (aka WinRT, Windows Store) applications. They can run on Desktop PC under Windows 8 pro and on portable pc under Windows 8 RT.

Also, WP8 and WinRT apps can use similar API, so you can have shared dlls. But you will have diffetent builds for both platforms.

Comment: Thanks @Anton, Do you know device driver model ? I am sure it is not the same way as Windows Mobile/CE, any pointers?

Comment: Your application will run in a sandbox. If you are not a MS partner,  you will not get any acces to hardware. So, in WP7 you can work with C# (Silverlight and XNA). Also, WP7 has a WinCE as a core. WP8 has WinRT core.